# How to switch default run terminal for VSCode with Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I select RUN for my PowerShell script it executes in my "Integrated PowerShell Console" which is running PowerShell 7.x.
Some of my scripts use commands that are not available in PS7 (yet?) but works in PS5.
I have a second Terminal running in VSCode running PS5 and I can paste the script there and it works.
How can I switch the functionality of RUN (F5) to execute the script in my second terminal window?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Shivam Jha for the link.

I tried to map F5 to "workbench.action.terminal.runActiveFile: Run the active file in the terminal instance." and that works except it can only run code from files, not code just entered in the editor and not yet saved.

The solution then is to have F5 mapped to workbench.action.debug.run and CTRL+F5 mapped to workbench.action.terminal.runActiveFile.

This way I can have several PowerShell terminals active and use CTRL+F5 to run the active file in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, untested, but to me, it seems promising.

Open two instances of vscode, open the same folder in both, and open the two different terminals, one in each instance. If it still takes the default terminal even if you open another one in advance, try running in interactive window. Also check whether running just a selection (then just select the whole file) might influence the chosen output terminal.